# Is it possible to get max id in filtered and limited queryset without fetching?

Tags: sql, django, postgresql

Suppose I have a table in db with rows like this:

| ID | Foo |
| --- | --- |
| 19 | 1 |
| 20 | 1 |
| 38 | 2 |
| 44 | 1 |
| 50 | 2 |
| 61 | 1 |

I want to get max id (`50` in this example) from queryset like this:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(foo=2).order_by('id').values_list('id')[:limit]
```

`limit`, of course, can be greater than total row number. I can do this by fetching all queryset, convert it to list and use the last item

```
list(MyModel.objects.filter(foo=2).order_by('id').values_list('id')[:limit])[-1]
```

but can I do this in database, without fetching entire queryset?

Raw sql solution is welcome too. DB is PostgreSQL.

**Update:**

I need max id of items inside limited set, not all table! For example if `limit == 1` if will be `38`, if `limit == 2` it will be `50` and if `limit == 500` it still will be `50`.

Comment: Do you mean to the the max *after* an arbitrary `LIMIT`?  Because otherwise, `LIMIT` stops making sense once you only want the max `id`. Well, `LIMIT` without deterministic `ORDER BY` is odd (and often questionable) to begin with. Clarify please.

Comment: @lampslave: the limit itself makes not much sense: a database table has no inherent order. So querying it might return records in any order, for example 38 might be first in one query, but second in another one, etc.

Comment: Thank you about order by, I knew it, but did not specify. I updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use:

```
from django.db.models import Max

MyModel.objects.filter(foo=2).aggregate(max=Max('id'))['max']
```

this will make a single query that will only return the greatest `id` for all `MyModel`s with `foo=2`.

As for getting the *n*-th, you can work with a union queryset, like:

```
qs = MyModel.objects.filter(foo=2)
list(
    qs.order_by('id')[limit - 1 : limit].union(qs.order_by('-id')[:1], all=True)
)[0].id
```

This will retrieve *at most* two records, one with the limit, and the last one. We then cast these to a list and return the first of the two. If the first one with the limit is missing, we get the last one (the second queryset). But these are retrieved in the same database query.

Comment: I need max id of rows inside limited set, not all table.

Comment: Great! Or even (I guess) qs.order_by('id')[limit - 1 : limit].union(qs.order_by('-id')[:1], all=True).first(), check if first is None (because table can be empty) and get id from it. Thank you a lot, I'll test this soon and accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is the max `id`, it's very basic:

```sql
SELECT max(id) AS id
FROM   tbl
WHERE  foo = 2;
```

If you need more columns or the whole row:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   tbl
WHERE  foo = 2
ORDER  BY id DESC
LIMIT  1;
```

IF `id` can be `null`, you'll probably want:

```
...
ORDER  BY id DESC NULLS LAST
...
```

See:

- [Sort by column ASC, but NULL values first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510509/sort-by-column-asc-but-null-values-first/9511492#9511492)

If the table is big and performance matters, a [multicolumn **index**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-multicolumn.html) on `(foo, id DESC)` would be ideal. (Or `(foo, id DESC NULLS LAST)` if `id` can be `null`.) Just on `(foo, id)` is almost as good. And if there are only few rows for the same `foo`, just on `(foo)` is typically good enough.